# moving excel files within single S3 bucket to a new subfolder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, boto3

Am stuck with this problem where I have to move multiple files within an S3 bucket to a different subfolder. But AWS CLI is not helping as the recursive option will loop through the entire branch.

Eg: file.xlsx should move from 
srce_bkt/processing/file.xlsx    to     srce_bkt/processing/2019-08-20/file.xlsx

Can we use boto3 for this.Tried but not working as expected.Please suggest

Comment: "Can we use boto3 for this." Yes definitely. "Tried but not working" Then post your code. You need to show what you have attempted if you want us to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit **rename** if you want to use `boto3`. What I've done previously is just create a duplicate of the file with the key updated (appending the folder) and then deleting the previous file if you don't need to keep it:

```
import boto3
SOURCE_BUCKET = "srce_bkt"
SOURCE_FOLDER = "processing"
TARGET_FOLDER = "processing/2019-08-20"

# Setup boto client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Get file list of all items
response = s3.list_objects(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, Prefix=SOURCE_FOLDER)
response_content = response.get("Contents", [])

# Iterate through file list
for s3_file in file_list:
    source_key = s3_file.get("Key", "")

    # Can do filtering here if you want, uncomment out if needed
    # if not source_key.endswith(".xlsx"):
    #    continue

    # Get base file name
    file_name = source_key.split('/')[-1]

    # Generate new key
    destination_key = "{}/{}".format(TARGET_FOLDER, file_name)

    # "Rename" file
    s3.copy(
        {
            "Bucket": SOURCE_BUCKET,
            "Key": source_key
        },
        SOURCE_BUCKET,
        destination_key
    )
    # Uncomment if you want to keep the original file
    s3.delete_object(Bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, Key=source_key)
```

References:

[s3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client)

[list_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects)

[copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy)

[delete_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object)

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no API to move objects but you can definitely copy and then delete the files.
Here is the description to use the API [Boto3 S3 Copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.copy)

For this requirement, you can simply use the same bucket name

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
  'Bucket': 'srce_bkt',
  'Key': 'processing/file.xlsx'
 }
bucket = s3.Bucket('srce_bkt')
bucket.copy(copy_source, 'processing/2019-08-20/file.xlsx')
```

To delete iterate over the bucket using this example [enter link description here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#list-objects-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket) and then delete with this API [enter link description here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.delete_objects)